# React Component not receiving my props in my state

Tags: reactjs

I have a form, which contains few fields that needs to be pre-filled based on the state value.

The problem actually is that when i log only the props I can find my Schema object with all necessary data, but when I log the state it appears undefined.

I tried to use `ComponentWillReceiveProps` to pass props to my state, but it did not work, maybe I misused it.

What approach I should use in this case ?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        display_name: this.props.Schema.display_name,
        phone: this.props.Schema.phone,
        email: this.props.Schema.email,
        activated: this.props.Schema.activated,
        groups: this.props.Schema.groups
    }
    console.log(props);
    console.log("state", this.state)
    this.editUser = this.editUser.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    this.setState({
        [target.name]: target.value 
    })
    console.log(this.state);
}

<input  type={i.type} 
    defaultValue={this.state.display_name} 
    name={this.state.display_name}
    id={this.state.id}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using state directly in the class body?

```
state = {
        display_name: this.props.Schema.display_name,
        phone: this.props.Schema.phone,
        email: this.props.Schema.email,
        activated: this.props.Schema.activated,
        groups: this.props.Schema.groups
}
```

> EDIT

try your willReceiveProps like this?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!_.isEqual(this.props.Schema, nextProps.Schema)) {
       this.setState({ display_name: nextProps.Schema.display_name, ...more})
    }
 }
```

Comment: yep, same result

Comment: Also, console.log is can evaluate the results when available. If the console.log variable shows a small "i" it means it was evaluated just now. So WillReceiveProps should be your go-to guy and update the state there with a check. Do you have a sandbox/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are putting `display_name: this.props.Schema.display_name,`
but then you do `console.log(props)`.

I think your issue here is that you need to:

```
this.state = {
    display_name: props.Schema.display_name,
    phone: props.Schema.phone,
    email: props.Schema.email,
    activated: props.Schema.activated,
    groups: props.Schema.groups
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do as in this example

```
render(){
    const schema = this.props.Schema
    return
      ( 
        <div>
         <input
           defaultValue={schema.display_name} 
         />
        </div>
      )
```

Comment: the problem is not populating the form. the problem is the state becoming undefined.